# How to retrieve images in a search engine?

Tags: php, css, image, search, rows

Thanks in advance.

I am stuck I have created a generic search engine by Nick Frost. However, I am lost on how to retrieve images from it, as it keeps coming back with errors whenever I add an image as part of the $row or add the HTML image source code.

Have I done something wrong?

My code is below:

```
 if ($numrows > 0)      
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
            $id = $row ['id'];
            $title = $row ['title'];
            $description = $row ['description'];
            $keywords = $row ['keywords'];
            $link = $row ['link'];
            $image = $row['images'];


            echo 
            "<nav class='table'>

                    <img src= width='50px' height='80px' 'data:image; base 64, $image'>

                    <br>

                    <a href='$link'> $title</a>

                    <br>

                    $description

                    <br>

            </nav> ";
    }
```

Comment: The top part got cut off:      if ($numrows > 0)

Comment: Show us the shortest example of the problem so we can test it.  Right now all I see relevant is the `img` tag that has an empty `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
echo "<nav class='table'>

                <img src= width='50px' height='80px' 'data:image; base 64, $image'>

                <br>

                <a href='$link'> $title</a>

                <br>

                $description

                <br>

        </nav> ";
```

With:

```
echo "<nav class='table'>

                <img src='data:image; base 64, ".$image."' width='50px' height='80px'>

                <br>

                <a href='$link'> $title</a>

                <br>

                $description

                <br>

        </nav> ";
```

Comment: Thank you Haresh. Much appreciated but will the php come up with an error as it is double quotations inside of double quotations? and it also says my $images is an undefined variable

Comment: @Mercury I don't think that there is any error,I am not using double quote inside double quote :) , Actually I am concatenate a variable in `echo` statement.